# How to publish jar to Nexus(snapshot repository)?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, gradle, nexus

## What I want to achieve

I want to publish jar to Nexus snapshot repository.

If you know how to realize, I would like to know.

## Detail

I'm planning to publish Java project artifacts (jar) using Gradle from the Jenkins Pipeline to the Nexus3 artifact repository. (But on requirements
  I can not use the `maven-publish` plugin for`build.gradle`. Using `maven-publish` as`gradle publish`, I confirms that I can publish to the snapshot repository)

I will publish jar from a Jenkins job.

I would like to publish to **snapshot repository** , but I was not able to investigate / implement various things.

### Survey / Confirmation

According to my research, it seems that there is already the following Jenkins Plugin

- [Nexus Artifact Uploader](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Nexus+Artifact+Uploader)
- [Nexus Platform Plugin for Jenkins](https://help.sonatype.com/integrations/nexus-and-continuous-integration/nexus-platform-plugin-for-jenkins)

However, neither plug-in seems to support Publish to the snapshot repository. (I tried for a while, but I got an error)

Also, calling API in the JenkinsPipeline script using `curl` was not permitted as follows:

```
        sh "curl -v -u admin:admin123 \
            -X POST http://localhost:8081/service/rest/v1/components?repository=maven=snapshots \
            -F maven2.groupId=${groupId} \
            -F maven2.artifactId=${artifactId} \
            -F maven2.version=${version} \
            -F maven2.asset1=build/libs/${artifactId}-${version}.jar \
            -F maven2.asset1.extension=jar \
            -F maven2.asset2=build/libs/${artifactId}-${version}.jar \
            -F maven2.asset2.classifier=javadoc \
            -F maven2.asset2.extension=jar \
            -F maven2.asset3=build/libs/${artifactId}-${version}.jar \
            -F maven2.asset3.classifier=sources \
            -F maven2.asset3.extension=jar"
        }
```

https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/115006744008-How-can-I-programmatically-upload-files-into-Nexus-3-

The error message when curling is as follows.

```
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> POST /service/rest/v1/components?repository=maven-snapshots HTTP/1.1

> Host: localhost:8081

> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4xMjM=

> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1

> Accept: */*

> Content-Length: 1379

> Expect: 100-continue

> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------bea51339dc9456fe

> 

< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

} [1379 bytes data]
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

< Date: Sat, 13 Jul 2019 11:18:22 GMT

< Server: Nexus/3.17.0-01 (OSS)

< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

< Vary: Accept

< Content-Type: application/vnd.siesta-validation-errors-v1+json

< X-Siesta-FaultId: 2281dcfa-6583-456a-9970-318d54dd431b

< Content-Length: 93

* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
< 

{ [93 bytes data]

100  1472  100    93  100  1379     93   1379  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01  2944
* Closing connection 0
[{"id":"*","message":"Upload to snapshot repositories not supported, use the maven client."}][Pipeline] error
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having this problem as well. What worked for me was making sure the version number had '-SNAPSHOT' at the end of it, like so: 'com.ex.example-1.0.3-SNAPSHOT' You cannot post a non-snapshot artifact to a snapshot repository in Nexus, and the same goes for a release repository.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Well, I understand that. Is it possible to publish snapshot artifacts to a snapshot repository??
Is the best way to publish [Apache Maven Deploy Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/)??

Comment: It is possible to publish a snapshot artifact to a snapshot repository. I use the gradle deploy task, but any deploy plugin that allows you to specify which type of artifact to publish(snapshot or nonsnapshot) to your nexus repository (snapshot or release, respectively) should be fine.

Comment: In general we use the gradle publish-plugin. I have confirmed that I can publish to snapshot.Thank you Xdude736 san!